# Can't select dropdown option based on database data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have three tables.

I need to select *multiple data* from dropdown and save that data with the hotel `id` column in the table `hotel_rooms`.

If the dropdown item is already in the `hotel_rooms` table, I need that option to be selected.

I can list out data in the dropdown. But my problem is, the already saved data in `hotel_rooms` is not selected.

Please check the attached image and given code and help me to solve this issue.

```
hotel
-----
id name address
42   taj  delhi

room
-----
id title
1   suit
2   deluxe
4   standard

hotel_rooms
-----------
hotel_id  room_id
42         1
42         2
42         4
```

Code

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="example-basic" size="5">
<?php
$hotel_id = $_GET['editID']; // Hotel ID = 42
$emailToRecord = array();
$select2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id IN ( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT room_id FROM hotel_rooms WHERE hotel_id = '$hotel_id' GROUP BY room_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) AS subquery )");
while ($row2 = $select2->fetch_array()) {
    $emailToRecord[$row2["id"]] = $row2;
}
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, title FROM rooms ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = $select->fetch_array()) {
    ?>
    <option class="hotelrooms" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"<?= $emailToRecord == $row['id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $row['title']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

[image]

### Firebug Inspect Result

```
<li class=" hotelrooms">
<label class="ui-corner-all" title="" for="ui-multiselect-0-option-0">
<input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-0" type="checkbox" title="" value="31" name="multiselect_0">
<span>rooms</span>
</label>
</li>
<li class=" hotelrooms">
<label class="ui-corner-all" title="" for="ui-multiselect-0-option-1">
<input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-1" type="checkbox" title="" value="30" name="multiselect_0">
<span>Dummy</span>
</label>
</li>
<li class=" hotelrooms">
<label class="ui-corner-all" title="" for="ui-multiselect-0-option-2">
<input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-2" type="checkbox" title="" value="29" name="multiselect_0">
<span>Tests</span>
</label>
</li>
<li class=" hotelrooms">
<label class="ui-corner-all" title="" for="ui-multiselect-0-option-3">
<input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-3" type="checkbox" title="" value="28" name="multiselect_0">
<span>Superior Zimmer Einzelnutzung</span>
</label>
</li>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `<?= $emailToRecord[$find] == $row['id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>` be using `<?php echo $email...` ? Inspect the element that should be selected and paste the HTML in your question please

Comment: Also, you are using the variable `$find` where is it defined?

Comment: Your `$select2` query returns empty result because of the condition `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` don't you think it should be `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1` @samsam

Comment: I would suggest to make sure your condition gets true - $emailToRecord == $row['id'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; I am wondering whether you get correct result in $emailToRecord & $row['id']..

Answer (score -1):

As you are having `multiple` `select` you have to do something like

```
//take all saved it array to variable
var valArr = [101,102];
i = 0, size = valArr.length;
for(i; i < size; i++){
  $("#data").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[value='"+valArr[i]+"']").attr("checked","checked");
  $("#data option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("selected", 1);
  $("#data").multiselect("refresh");
}
```

Comment: @sam sam please check my answer